# Uniform convergence to a differentiable function

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded sequence.
Prove that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^{2x}}$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $(1, +\infty)$ to a differentiable function $f$.

The result that the series converges absolutely and uniformly comes from the M- test so there exists a function $f$ that the series converges uniformly. How that to prove that the function is differentiable? This where I am stuck.

Edit: I thought the last part of the question was something I was overseeing. However, I cannot proceed .. I have a feeling that I should use the boundness of the sequence... but I cannot see how it will work.

*Suggestions?*

Comment: Consider the series of the derivatives.

Comment: You mean differentiate? And that would leave where exaclty? I am trying to get a point here.

Comment: Do you have in mind to use the theorem of the derivatives? Is this to what you're trying to guide me?

Comment: If you have a finite sum of differentiable functions, the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivatives. For an infinite series, one expects that in nice cases, the analogue holds. So one can look at the series of the derivatives. If that series behaves nicely, one can then use the fundamental theorem of calculus to show that it is indeed the derivative of the series. In the case here, everything behaves nicely.

Comment: The derivative of the series here is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-2 a_n \ln n}{n^{2x}}$$

if I have not made any mistakes. But this is just the sum of the derivatives. Now, I just examine if the new series converges uniformly to the derivatives?

Comment: You check whether that series (no mistakes in the differentiation, by the way) converges uniformly to _something_, let's call it $g$. You should find that it does, hence $g$ is continuous. Then check that $g$ is the derivative of $f$. Since you don't know yet that you can differentiate $f$, it may be a good idea to ... do something with $g$.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was referring to. But I had in mind a theorem (theorem of the derivatives) that extracts the conclusion right away. Thank you for explaining in detail... Got it!!

Comment: If $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ and $f_n'$ converges locally uniformly to $g$, then $f$ is differentiable and $f' = g$? That's the one I was aiming at. If you know some complex analysis, a theorem of Weierstraß gives you the conclusion, since the original series converges uniformly on the half-plane $\{ z : \operatorname{Re} z > 1\}$, and the terms are holomorphic.

Comment: Yes, mr. Daniel I got the point.. that's the thoerem I was referring to.

Comment: By the way, hmm.. I am having a trouble using the M-test for the series of the derivatives. After I differentiate , how would I bound that? That $\ln n$ causes me some trouble.

Comment: Use $\ln n < \sqrt{n}$ for example. Or $\ln n < C_\varepsilon\cdot n^\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ if you want to show the differentiability on $\bigl(\frac{1}{2},+\infty\bigr)$.